# How to determine size in bytes of H2O frame in Python?

Tags: python, h2o

I am loading Spark dataframes into H2O (using Python) for building machine learning models. It has been recommended to me that I should allocate an H2O cluster with RAM 2-4x as big as the frame I will be training on, so that the analysis fits comfortably within memory. But I don't know how to precisely estimate the size of an H2O frame.

So supposing I have an H2O frame already loaded into Python, how do I actually determine its size in bytes? An approximation within 10-20% is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will show a summary of the underlying representation in H2O's key-value store, including the full byte size:

```
frame.describe(chunk_summary=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This refers to 2-4 times the size of the file on disk, so rather than looking at the memory in Python, look at the original file size.  Also, the 2-4x recommendation varies by algorithm (GLM & DL will requires less memory than tree-based models).

Comment: The H2O frame is generated by converting from a Spark dataframe with various transforms applied (which was itself originally generated from a Hive query). It doesn't directly correspond to a file on disk, as far as I am aware.